# Which OAuth2 Grant Type Should I Use For ios client?

Tags: ios, django, django-rest-framework

I just made a django rest api with DRF. I need to register an app for my ios app, but I'm not sure which grant type to use. I'm thinking I should use implicit, as the ios client can't keep the secret from the user. The user needs to login before entering the ios app to GET and POST. Is this the right or should I use Authorizaton Code? tq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the iOS client is a 'trusted' i.e. is your own app using your own api, you can use [Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3). If another app is using your api, the api should force them to use a user-agent for [Authorization Code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.1).
Implicit is generally not recommended. "When using the implicit grant type, the access token is transmitted in the URI fragment, which can expose it to unauthorized parties."

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.16

Comment: I'll go ahead with Resource Owner Password Credentials then. Thank you for adding the RFC links.

Comment: A quick follow up question, in the case of my own app using my own api, would the client type be confidential or public?

Comment: If it is a mobile client, the client type would be public.
http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-2.1

Comment: Opps, I forgot to mention it is for my iOS app. Thank you again.